# Upload video to server using rn-fetch-blob react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Hello there i am trying to upload a video to server using rn-fetch-blob.Here is my code.

```
 var tempParam = 
    [{
      name: 'video', filename: 'vid.mp4', data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(videoUri.uri), type:'video/mp4'
    },
    {
      name:'user_id',data:'1060'
    }]

    console.log(JSON.stringify(tempParam))

    RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', url, {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream',
    },tempParam)
    .uploadProgress((written, total) => {
      var perc = ((((written / total)*100).toFixed(2))*1) +  "%" 
      console.log('uploaded', perc)

      Platform.OS === 'android' 
      ?  ToastAndroid.show('Uploaded..'+perc.toString(), ToastAndroid.SHORT)
      : Alert.alert('Uploaded..'+perc.toString())
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      if(!responseJson.error){
        this.setState({loading_status:false})

                    Platform.OS === 'android' 
                  ?  ToastAndroid.show('Video added successfully', ToastAndroid.SHORT)
                  : Alert.alert('Video added successfully')

                }
                else{

                  Platform.OS === 'android' 
                  ? ToastAndroid.show(responseJson.message, ToastAndroid.SHORT)
                  : Alert.alert(responseJson.message)
                }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      this.setState({loading_status:false})
      Platform.OS === 'android' 
                            ?   ToastAndroid.show("Try Again", ToastAndroid.SHORT)
                            : Alert.alert("Try Again !")
      console.log(err);
    })
```

where videoUri.uri is the uri of the video taken from

```
react-native-image-picker
```

During uploading of video after uploading some part of video this throws an error that

```
stream was reset: PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

How can i solve this issue ? Pleas help me

Answer (score 0):

content-type of the POST request from application/json to multipart/form-data

multipart/form-data is used to upload files of MIME-compatible representation, such as pictures and video files, and related metadata a single POST request.

```
'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'
```

check out my working example

```
export const uploadVideo = file => RNFetchBlob.fetch(
  'POST',
   url,
  {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
  [{
    type: 'video/mp4',
    name: 'file',
    filename: 'vid.mp4',
    data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(file.uri),
  }],
);
```

Comment: Previously i was using that only but that also does not works !

Comment: check now I have update the code with my working code

Comment: this code format is same like me and sorry to say but this format also does not works